# Concise replacement for long list of Try-Except statement in Python?

Tags: python

I have this long list of try except statement:

```
    try:
       uri = entry_obj['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
       uri = None
    try:
       position = entry_obj['yt$position']['$t']
    except KeyError:
       position = None
    try:
       description = entry_obj['content']['$t']
    except KeyError:
       description = None
    try:
       seconds = entry_obj['media$group']['yt$duration']['seconds']
    except KeyError:
       seconds = None
    try:
       thumbnails = entry_obj['media$group']['media$thumbnail']
    except KeyError:
       thumbnails = None
```

Is there a more concise way to write this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you tire of figuring out what to use for default values in `get()` calls, just write a helper function:

```
def resolve(root, *keys):
   for key in keys:
       try:
           root = root[key]
       except (KeyError, IndexError):
           return None
   return root
```

Then you just write, e.g.:

```
uri = resolve(entry_obj, 'media$group', 'media$content', 0, 'url')
```

To simplify the calls a little, you might beef up the helper function to take a single string for the keys and split on spaces; that way you don't have to type so many quotes, and we can also add a default value argument:

```
def resolve(root, keys, default=None):
    for key in keys.split():
        try:
            root = root[key]
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            try:
                root = root[int(key)]
            except (IndexError, ValueError, KeyError):
                return default

uri = resolve(entry_obj, 'media$group media$content 0 url', '')
```

Comment: +1 For the writing a function to do something generically when you find yourself doing similar things repetitively. I am often surprised by how often programmers don't do this. The second version looks ugly to me though; now keys can't contain spaces, and can't be anything other than strings in dicts or ints in lists. The first one supports looking up a chain of keys in nested containers, where all you need is something that supports `__getitem__` and throws a KeyError or IndexError if the key is not found. You can always type a big long string and .split() it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, the second one does have the limitation that it only supports strings and ints, and the strings can't contain spaces.

Comment: kindall, what do you think about the method I just posted for replacing try-excepts? I'm kinda new to python, so not sure if it's a bad use of lambda

Answer (score 2):

I thought of another good way to do this, not sure how it compares to kindall's method. We first define a method property:

```
def res(self, property):
    try:
        return property()
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

Then replace the try-except statements with:

```
    url = res(lambda: entry_obj['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'])
    position = res(lambda: entry_obj['yt$position']['$t'])
    description = res(lambda: entry_obj['content']['$t'])
    duration = res(lambda: entry_obj['media$group']['yt$duration']['seconds'])
    thumbnails = res(lambda: entry_obj['media$group']['media$thumbnail'])
```

Comment: That's fun and a good alternative. You can even make that more generic by allowing the caller to optionally pass in the exceptions to be caught and the desired default value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of dictionaries instead:

```
position = entry_object.get('yt$position').get('$t')
```

`get` will handle the case of a key not existing for you, and give you a (changable) fallback value instead in that case. You'll still need to handle the first `IndexError` manually, but all the ones that are just `except KeyError:` will disappear.

Comment: You'd need to pass `{}` as the default to the first `get` in order for the second one to gracefully default if the first one did. That's alright for two lookups, but `seconds = entry_obj.get('media$group', {}).get('yt$duration', {}).get('seconds')` is pretty horrible. And this plain doesn't work for cases like the first line of the example, where it's not all `dict` lookups (not that we know for certain that the rest are, either, though `.get` is usually pretty safe on a "dict-like" object).

Comment: To add to this: If you plan carefully, your default value lets you continue with evaluating the rest of the expression. For example, the first assignment in the OP's code snippet can be written: `uri = entry_obj.get('media$group', {}).get('media$content', [{}])[0].get('url')`. The `[{}]` on the `get` for `media$content` returns a single-element list with an empty dictionary, allowing the next two operations to always succeed.